# Event fired several times when i scroll down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to display some data when the user scroll down the page but the ajax called is done at least 2 times and sometimes 4 times. Is there anyway to execute the ajax call only one time ? Thanks.

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
                $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : $('#AjaxMoreStatus').attr("data-url"),
                dataType : "HTML",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('.spinner').show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('.spinner').hide();
                },
                success : function (data) {
                    $('#AjaxMoreStatus').append(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use named setTimeout with clearTimeout.

Comment: Could you not just create a `bool` variable and then simply change the `bool` value when they have scrolled so you no longer attempt to do the ajax call.

Comment: @Canvas I am not sure if `bool` would be the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `.scroll()` event and when the `window` is scrolled, it gets fired multiple times. This is an expected behaviour. The best way is to use a timer, for like `500ms` and wait for the browser to stop scrolling:

```
var tmr = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
  clearTimeout(tmr);
  $('.spinner').show();
  tmr = setTimeout(function () {
    if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
      $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : $('#AjaxMoreStatus').attr("data-url"),
        dataType : "HTML",
        beforeSend: function() {
          $('.spinner').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
          $('.spinner').hide();
        },
        success : function (data) {
          $('#AjaxMoreStatus').append(data);
        }
      });
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

This would also save your AJAX polling to server too many times. You may also take the contents of `beforeSend()` to the top of the AJAX call and timer.

Comment: Thanks ! You explanation are really clear and the code works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a known issue and it is solved by a technique called `debouncing logic`.

> What is Debouncing logic: Which Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not be triggered.
>    The function will be called after it stops being called for N
>   milliseconds. If **immediate** is passed, trigger the function on the leading edge, instead of the trailing.

---

**Debouncing logic:**

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
     var context = this, args = arguments;
     var later = function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
     };
     var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
     clearTimeout(timeout);
     timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
     if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

//target code/callback to be called on scroll/resize event
function callback() {
    clearTimeout(tmr);
   $('.spinner').show();
   tmr = setTimeout(function () {
     if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())  {
      $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : $('#AjaxMoreStatus').attr("data-url"),
        dataType : "HTML",
        beforeSend: function() {
          $('.spinner').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
          $('.spinner').hide();
        },
        success : function (data) {
          $('#AjaxMoreStatus').append(data);
        }
    });
  }
}

//registering callback function to debouncing logic
$(window).scroll(function () {
     debounce(callback, 250);
}
```

Now using `debouncing` logic, not only you can solve your current problem but also you can stop worrying about when the user would stop scrolling the page so that you can call your target function, as it may go on for `500` milli seconds or even till `1` sec.

The above code is generic , so you dont have to make any assumptions about user interaction on your script.

*Ref:https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function*